# AngularJS Redirect Hashbang to Hashban exclamationmark?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

currently I'm trying to move my ui-router to `#!` from a simple Hashbang Prefix `#` however if I change my locationProvider to it:

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
```

It will always return a 404 if I try to access it via the old url.
So if somebody has a hyperlink to `#/customer/list` it will redirect to a 404 or the default page, is there a way to redirect it to `#!/customer/list`? (I actually have a lot of routes so it should be as automatic as possible).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `$stateChangeStart` as follows:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    if (/\#(?!\!)/.test(toState)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        toState.replace("#","#!");
        $state.go(toState);
    } else {
        angular.noop;
    }
});
```

**EDIT :**

Not tried. But, hope it works:

```
$transitions.onStart({}, function(a) {
    var toState = a.$to().url.pattern;
    if (/\#(?!\!)/.test(toState)) {
      toState.replace("#", "#!");
      $state.go(toState)
    } else {
      angular.noop;
    }
});
```

All the best.

Comment: isn't the $stateChangeStart event deprecated?  is there a way to do it with transitions?